# passing values from a form to another form in acces 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a login form and I would like to store the login Id in a variable. then I need this variable in the other Form to do a lookup.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just create a Public variable like this:

```vb
Public strLogin As String
```

Then after they log into your system you can simply just save whatever information you would like into that variable.  That variable will then be [useable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241.aspx#sectionSection0) anywhere else you need it until the database is closed.